# Replacing one ssh server by another while keeping keys

Tags: ssh

I have an embedded system that normally connects via ssh to a certain system, the OS is on flash mem and nothing can be changed.

I have now replaced the destination system with another and thanks to iptables rules the embedded system goes to the correct new destination.

I have taken the entire .ssh/ of the old system and put on the new one, but upon connection attempt, I get:

```
Host key mismatch for dest-system !
Fingerprint is md5 41:ba:3c:f1:0b:f6:21:58:2c:ce:cb:52:30:c1:c1:19
Expected md5 9f:e2:51:98:4d:49:4a:d5:eb:1d:f5:18:62:3f:6c:b7
If you know that the host key is correct you can
remove the bad entry from ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Since I cannot change the known_hosts (read-only OS), I don't understand why copying the .ssh didn't work. Is it because the IPs are different ?

PS: is that akin to a MITM ?

Comment: You need to copy the **server** keys from the old system to the new one, not the user keys, which is what seems you've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The host keys are stored in `/etc/ssh`. Each server will generate new ones (obviously different), but you can just copy them to replacement server.

Comment: I copied the whole /etc/ssh but I still get the same error message, only the fingerprint md5 has changed. The embedded system tried to log into a user account, not a root account if that changes anything.

Comment: The known_hosts file on the client side is read only?

Comment: Yes, the client OS is basically read-only (reset after each reboot). I think my problem is that the server keys have been changed at a certain point and the embedded device needs the old ones. Unfortunately they have not been kept.

Comment: I managed to find the original server keys on an old backup, so now it works. Thanks.